Is Streamlit Feasible for an Application with Multi-User Authentication and 25 Pages?
I'm considering using Streamlit for developing an application that requires authentication for multiple users. The application will have a total of 25 pages, and each page will contain different functionalities and data visualizations.
Key requirements include:
Multi-user authentication (registration, login, and session management)
Handling user roles and permissions
Navigating between multiple pages with dynamic content
Scalability for potentially more users in the future
Is Streamlit suitable for this kind of application, or would another framework be more appropriate? What are the potential challenges I might face using Streamlit for a multi-user, multi-page application?
I'd appreciate any advice or insights from those who have experience with similar use cases.
